# extraer datos e insertar en inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax, json

Hola buen día comunidad,
tengo un formulario el cual al momento de poner un dato en el primer input y darle enter traiga información de una base de datos y dicha informacion se coloquen en los otros campos del formulario en caso de que exista y si no estan los datos solo lance alguna alerta al momento tengo esto...

```
<form method="post" id="insert_datos_transporte">

        <input type="hidden" name="numero_embarque" id="numero_embarque" class="form-control" />
        <input type="hidden" name="tipo_embarque" id="tipo_embarque" class="form-control" />
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>id:</label>
            <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="" placeholder="id alumno" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre del Chofer" >
        </div>

        <label for="">Apellidos:</label>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido_paterno" name="apellido_paterno" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido_materno" name="apellido_materno" placeholder="Apellido Materno">
            </div>
        </div>

    <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="insertar" id="insertar" value="Insertar" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
        <br><br>

        <div id="alerta">
            <p>perosna no encontrada</p>
        </div>

    </form>
```

index.js

```
let inputCargar = document.getElementById('insertar');

const cargarContenido = () => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", "conexiones.php", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        console.log(xhr.readyState);
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
            let json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            let nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
            nombre.innerHTML = json.data.nombre;
        }
    }
    xhr.send();

}

inputCargar.addEventListener('keypress', cargarContenido);
```

json.js

```
{
data: [
{
id_alumno: "1",
id: "JAL0053522",
nombre: "Eder Jhonatan",
apellido_p: "Solis",
apellido_m: "Perez",
observaciones: "suspendido por robar",
estado: "-1"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

A tu boton no lo declares como tipo submit:

```
  <button id="btnInsertar" onclick="cargarContenido()" value="Insertar" ></button>
```

con eso ya tienes el llamado a tu funcion.

Comment: estoy haciendo pruebas como me lo mencionan pero al poner la funcion dentro del boton solo repito la funcion ya que tambien la tengo declarada en el index.js y realice un console log y si me trae los datos solo poniendo json me trae todos pero al querer acceder hasta json.data.nombre me marca undefined

Comment: en todo caso si revisas tu objeto json es un arreglo no un objeto [
{
id_alumno: "1"...}] , para un arreglo algo asi: data[0].nombre

Comment: Podría funcionar el data[0].nombre pero pues no siempre tiene que haber un sólo alumno, hazlo con un for que tenga un index para que sepas la posición exacta donde está para que quede data[i].nombre.